# Implicit instantiation of undefined template

Tags: c++, templates

Here's a template (queue) I'm trying to write:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Queue
{
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &, const Queue<T> & );
private:
    template<class> class Node;
    Node<T> *front;
    Node<T> *back;
public:
    Queue() : front(0), back(0) {}
    ~Queue();
    bool Empty()
    {
        return front == 0;
    }
    void Push(const T& NewEl)
    {
        Node<T&> *El = new Node<T> (NewEl);
        if (Empty())
            front=back=El;
        else
        {
            back-> next = El;
            back = El;
        }
    }
    void Pop()
    {
        if (Empty())
            cout << "Очередь пуста." << endl;
        else
        {
            Node<T> *El = front;
            front = front -> next;
            delete El;
        }
    }
    void Clear()
    {
        while (! Empty())
            Pop();
    }
};

template <typename T>
class Node
{
    friend class Queue<T>;
public:
    Node() {next = 0;}
    Node(T nd) {nd=node; next=0;}
    T& getsetnode(){return node;}
    Node<T>*& getsetnext(){return next;}
private:
    T front;
    T back;
    T node;
    Node<T> *next;
};

template <class T> ostream& operator<< (ostream &, const Queue<T> & );

int main()
{
    Queue<int> *queueInt = new Queue<int>;
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
        queueInt->Push(i);
        cout << "Pushed " << i << endl;
    }
    if (!queueInt->Empty())
    {
        queueInt->Pop();
        cout << "Pop" << endl;
    }
    queueInt->Front();
    queueInt->Back();
    queueInt->Clear();
    cout << "Clear" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

At these lines:

```
    Node<T&> *El = new Node<T> (NewEl);

    front = front -> next;
    delete El;
```

I get `Implicit instantiation of undefined template 'Queue<int>::Node<int>'`. What am I doing wrong? After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626033/implicit-instantiation-of-undefined-template-class) I tried changing `int` to `const int` to see if that was the problem, but apparently it isn't, because I get the same error.

I'm using XCode with LLVM compiler 4.2. When I switch to GCC I get more errors:

`template<class> class Node;` gets `Declaration of 'struct Queue<int>::Node<int>'`, 
`Node<T&> *El = new Node<T> (NewEl);` gets `Invalid use of incomplete type`, 
and anything dealing with assignment of anything to El can't convert `<int&>*` to `<int>*` (but deleting reference doesn't change anything for LLVM).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
template <typename T>
class Queue
{
private:
    template<class> class Node;
/* ... */
```

This is a forward declaration of `Queue::Node`. The latter defined `class Node` is in the global namespace, so they aren't the same and any usage of `Queue::Node` will result in an incomplete-type error. Since you don't provide an interface to the interior nodes anyway just scrap the global definition of `Node` and stick it into `Queue`:

```
template <typename T>
class Queue
{
private:
    class Node
    {
    public:
    Node() {next = 0;}
    /* ... */
     };
/* ... */
};
```