# Compile error with variadic templates and overloaded << operator

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to create a class that would store a tuple of vectors. I have a strange compilation error whose origin I don't understand.

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

/// Suppose T is a pack of primitive types
/// VectorTuple defines a tuple of vectors of these types

template <typename... T>
struct VectorTuple;

template <typename T>
struct VectorTuple<T>
{
  using data_type = std::tuple<std::vector<T>>;
};

template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct VectorTuple<T1, T2>
{
  using data_type = std::tuple<std::vector<T1>, std::vector<T2>>;
};

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
struct VectorTuple<T1, T2, T3>
{
  using data_type = std::tuple<std::vector<T1>, std::vector<T2>, std::vector<T3>>;
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <size_t I, size_t N, typename... T>
struct DataAlgorithm
{
  static void resize(typename VectorTuple<T...>::data_type &data, const size_t size)
  {
    std::get<I>(data).resize(size);
    DataAlgorithm<I + 1, N, T...>::resize(data, size);
  }
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <size_t N, typename... T>
struct DataAlgorithm<N, N, T...>
{
  static void resize(typename VectorTuple<T...>::data_type &data, const size_t size)
  {
    std::get<N>(data).resize(size);
  }
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <typename... StoredTypes>
class MultiArray
{

public:
  enum
  {
    NFields = sizeof...(StoredTypes)
  };

  using value_types = std::tuple<StoredTypes...>;

  void resize(const size_t size)
  {
    DataAlgo<0, NFields - 1, StoredTypes...>::resize(m_values, size);
  }

private:
  template <size_t I, size_t N, typename... T>
  using DataAlgo = DataAlgorithm<I, N, T...>;

  using storage_type = typename VectorTuple<StoredTypes...>::data_type;

  /// The actual data stored
  storage_type m_values;
};


// This doesn't compile when array is const&, but works with non-const reference
template <typename... StoredTypes>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const MultiArray<StoredTypes...> &array)
{
  os << std::endl; // This is line 86 in the compiler error message
  return os;
}

int main()
{
  MultiArray<double, int, float> array;

  return 0;
}
```

I'm not able to overload the "<<" operator with `const MultiArray<...>&` as parameter. Clang 3.9.0 says:

```
compile_error.cpp: In instantiation of ‘class MultiArray<>’:
compile_error.cpp:86:14:   required from here
compile_error.cpp:75:71: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct VectorTuple<>’
   using storage_type = typename VectorTuple<StoredTypes...>::data_type;
                                                                       ^
compile_error.cpp:9:8: note: declaration of ‘struct VectorTuple<>’
 struct VectorTuple;
```

If I understand correctly, the compiler is not able to deduce the parameter types and tries to instantiate `VectorTuple` with no parameters whatsoever. Could you please help me fix this? Thank you.

This problem seems to be similar to the one described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626033/implicit-instantiation-of-undefined-template-class).

I also have a bonus question (but this should perhaps go to another post). Is there a more generic way of transforming a parameter pack of primitive types to a tuple of vectors of these types? It would be nice to replace the explicit enumeration of different variants of `VectorTuple` based on increasing number of template parameters by something like this:

```
template<typename ... T> struct TransformToVectors { /* ?? implementation ?? */ };
```

such that

```
TransformToVectors<double, int, float>::type
```

would be an alias for

```
std::tuple<std::vector<double>, std::vector<int>, std::vector<float>>
```

I tried to build the type recursively from instances with lower number of template parameters, but didn't get very far.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Submitted [78457](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=78457)

Comment: Thank you for submitting the bug report.

Comment: @Barry Not a compiler bug. See my analysis of an analogous situation in https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69116#c2

Comment: @T.C. But according to [temp.deduct.call]/6, the function parameter is a non-deduced context only if it is *a function type, function pointer type, or pointer to member function type*, which is not the case here. What am I missing?

Comment: @bogdan [temp.deduct.type]/5.5. IOW, [temp.deduct.call]/6 must be read as not implying the "only" you added.

Comment: @T.C. I'm not sure I agree with that reading. If [temp.deduct.call]/6 applies for all forms of function parameters, why does it begin with *When P is a [...]*? Looking at [CWG352](http://wg21.link/cwg352), which introduced [temp.deduct.type]/5.5, they were only looking at function parameters having one of those forms. Also, 5.5 says *[...] for which argument deduction cannot be done because [...]*; where is that deduction specified? It's a function call, so it's in [temp.deduct.call]; we look there and the only paragraph that says how overload set arguments are handled is p6, which applies...

Comment: @T.C. ... to specific forms of `P`. If the intent is indeed for it to apply in all cases, then the first line should be removed. Compilers do seem to apply it in all cases, so it could be a matter of adjusting the text to conform to the implementations. I find this a bit too flexible though; if I were to decide, I would lean towards adjusting 5.5 instead, to clarify that it applies only to specific forms of `P`.

Comment: @bogdan  I think the most sane reading is that [temp.deduct.type]/5.5 says that in general it's a nondeduced context, while [temp.deduct.call]/6 carves out a special case when `P` is one of the things listed and allows for trial deduction. In all other cases, "deduction cannot be done" because there's no sane `A` for an overload set. That's consistent with all implementations I know of.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128703/discussion-between-bogdan-and-t-c).

Answer (score 0):

For the bonus question

> Is there a more generic way of transforming a parameter pack of
>   primitive types to a tuple of vectors of these types? It would be nice
>   to replace the explicit enumeration of different variants of
>   VectorTuple based on increasing number of template parameters by
>   something like this:
>
> ```
> template<typename ... T> struct TransformToVectors { /* ? implementation ?? */ };
> ```
>
> such that
>
> ```
> TransformToVectors<double, int, float>::type
> ```
>
> would be an alias for
>
> ```
> std::tuple<std::vector<double>, std::vector<int>, std::vector<float>>
> ```

What's wrong with

```
template<typename ... T>
struct TransformToVectors
 { using type = std::tuple<std::vector<T>...>; };
```

?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with this :) I didn't know it was possible. Thank you.